# Why Android & IOS11 cannot communicate via NFC

Tags: android, ios, iphone, nfc, nfc-p2p

Currently using React Native and attempting to use [react-native-nfc-ios](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-nfc-ios) and [react-native-nfc](https://github.com/Novadart/react-native-nfc) so I can have cross-device communication between ios and Android. I'm finding that they cannot communicate, however I think it's due to a broader issue (as other existing apps also don't work).

**If I download a NFC reader app on iPhone 7, and an NFC writer app on Android they cannot communicate.** Why is this?

**Instructions to Duplicate**

1. Turn on NFC Reader on iPhone 7
2. Put some arbitrary data in NFC write mode on Android
3. Bringing devices together has no effect.

Not understanding the intricacies of NFC, it's hard for me as a casual programmer to understand what the actual problem is.

I understand that IOS11 on iPhone 7 (plus) supports NFC read, and generally speaking there are *card emulation, peer to peer, and read write modes*.

- Should they not communicate? The iPhone is not able to pick up the
  Android writer. Why is this?
- How does card emulation (I assume to be Apple Pay), differ from a write mode?

Comment: This does not appear to be a programming question. Please delete and post in a more appropriate place.

Comment: I'm currently using react-native-nfc-ios, and was experiencing the same issues and couldn't figure out why. This is the easiest way to communicate the issue.

Comment: @rmaddy added additional information to make it more programming relevant

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason is because Apple's iOS 11 update only allows reading from NFC tags (writing is only permitted for Apple Pay). At the moment, their software does not share the same enjoyment afforded by Android phones which enable card emulation, peer-to-peer, and reader/writer NFC usage. So our only hope is to wait for a software update that will finally enable this existing feature for developers to use.

Comment: It's so sad. I was heartbroken when I found this out. Thanks